# Using variable to specify floating point precision of hover text in plotly using python

Tags: python, plotly-python

I would like to pass a variable, in this case `precision` for defining the floating points in plotly `hovertemplate= "%{y:.2f}`.

Is there a way of doing this? Below is a working sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = "notebook_connected"

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3,4,5], b=[0.1,0.22,0.333, 0.4444, 0.55555]))
precision = 2
fig = px.line(df, x="a", y="b")

#         
fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate= "%{y:.3f}", hoverinfo="x + y") 
# would like to use a variable to define floating point precision
# Something  like: hovertemplate= "%{y:.precisionf}"

fig.update_layout(
   template="plotly_white",
   title='Sample Plot',
   xaxis_range= [0, 6],
   
   xaxis=dict(
       tickmode="linear",
       dtick=1,
       mirror=True,
       ticks="outside",
       showline=True,
       linewidth=1,
       linecolor="#A6C4EF",
   ),
   yaxis=dict(
       tickmode="linear",
       tick0=5,
       dtick=0.1,
       mirror=True,
       ticks="outside",
       showline=True,
       linewidth=1,
       linecolor="#A6C4EF",
   ),
   
   xaxis_title='a',
   yaxis_title='b',
   legend_title="LEGEND",
   legend=dict(bordercolor="#A6C4EF", borderwidth=1),
   hovermode="x unified",
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use f-strings

```
precision = 2
fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate= f"%{{y:.{precision}f}}", hoverinfo="x + y")
```

In f-strings the `{{` is an escape sequence for `{` if you want to add those to your strings.